# Ubuntu 22.04.1: apt-offline get --bundle option not working

Tags: apt-offline

**--bundle file.zip** option is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Ubuntu 22.04.1

```
~ $ apt-offline set --update --upgrade offline.sig
~ $ apt-offline get offline.sig --bundle offline.zip

Fetching APT Data

Downloading http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/Release.gpg                                                             
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/Release.gpg done                                                             
Exception in thread Thread-1 (run):#############] 100.0% of 0 KiB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_offline_core/AptOfflineLib.py", line 691, in run
    if threading.currentThread().guiTerminateSignal:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1449, in currentThread
    warnings.warn('currentThread() is deprecated, use current_thread() instead',
DeprecationWarning: currentThread() is deprecated, use current_thread() instead

Downloaded data to offline.zip
```

As you can see **--bundle offline.zip** doesn't really download anything other PGP signature.

**-d DIRECTORY** option works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the exact same issue. Was able to resolve by editing my threading.py file (/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py), finding every time warnings.warn() function was called, and commenting these lines out.

Not the proper fix, but it did get the proper download process started for me.